# docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I've just installed the Docker and it seems to me that I did not configure properly, because a simple test:

```
docker run hello-world
```

gives the following output

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

If I check

```
   Sudo service docker status
```

The output is

```
 Docker is not running
```

However, even if I restart Docker first

```
sudo service docker restart
 * Starting Docker: docker
```

and then run hello-world, I will have the same Cannot connect to the Docker daemon output.  How to fix it?

PS.  I didn't mention that I use Ubuntu via WSL.

Comment: have you tried: `sudo docker run hello-world` ?

Comment: Ooh, just noticed that it is not running, try looking at the logs to understand why it fails to start in the first place.

Comment: can you date your question with OS and version you installed?

Comment: @Jinna Balu, My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (Actually, it is a windows subsystem, but I suppose it doesn't matter much in the context of my issue)

Comment: @JorgeCampos, it seems that I don't have any logs :
 "journalctl -u docker.service" yeilds  "No journal files were found. -- No entries --"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the problem is in WSL.

Turned out that WSL does not support cgroups (which is necessary to run the Docker). Therefore the asked question doesn't make much sense, because it is not possible to use Docker if it is installed inside in WSL. Instead, Docker must be installed in Windows and this fact must be pointed at in settings of WSL Ubuntu.

If someone also stumbled upon this error, read more about this problem [here](https://medium.com/@sebagomez/installing-the-docker-client-on-ubuntus-windows-subsystem-for-linux-612b392a44c4)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 April 2018 update has just been released and now you can run the Docker engine inside WSL.
Just remember to open an elevated WSL shell (Run as Admin) before running the docker daemon.

```
sudo cgroupfs-mount
sudo service docker start
```

Answer (score 0):

Either run "docker run" as root or add your userid to docker group "sudo usermod -aG docker userid"

Comment: Unfortunately,
"sudo docker run" yeilds the same output, "sudo usermod -aG docker userid" adds userid to docker group but it doesn't change anything else   --- I still get "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix" outpput if tryingt run hello-world test.